# Same product showing multiple times in shopping cart

Tags: magento-1.9

I am having a strange issue that if i add a product to cart and then logout of my account, then after logging out i am adding same product to cart. Now when i login i should see same product with quantity 2 but the product is showing multiple times.
How to fix this?

Comment: are you using any theme ?

Comment: Yes, but it shouldn't be a theme issue ?

Comment: switch to rwd and check once..